# Vue delete current data values after @changed from select box

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a query that gets a record and display it to a graph. I can already display the records but when I click a record without a result and then click the previous with a result. The `data` property in vue adds the current result resulting to append the previous one. What I want is when I select another option from the `select` tag, the current data will be deleted and will be replaced with the current result with the new one.

Here is my Graph
[image]

When i clicked `Vince` from the select box I got the exact data and the graph. here is my Vue devtools details

[image]

But when I click `mark` the second teacher which has NO data or result
[image]

the data from my previous array is still in there and when I click back to `vince` which has a data in it here is the result

[image]

and the graph is like this

[image]

My code right now is which is not working

```
   getdata() {
                    let self = this
                    axios.get('/getGraph/' + self.teacher)
                        .then(({
                            data
                        }) => {
                            if(data.length > 0){
                                data.splice()
                            }
                            else{
                                data.date.forEach(x => {
                                self.dataSource.data.push(x);
                            });
                            }
                        })
                }
```

My original code is this

```
     getdata() {
                    let self = this
                    axios.get('/getGraph/' + self.teacher)
                        .then(({
                            data
                        }) => {
                            data.date.forEach(x => {
                                self.dataSource.data.push(x);
                            });
                        })
                },
                getTeachers() {
                    axios.get('getTeachers')
                        .then((res) => {
                            this.teachers = res.data
                        })
                        .catch((e) => {
                            console.log(e)
                        })
                }
```

Could someone tell me what is wrong and how could I achieve what i want to do? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear your data everty time you recieved data from the server like this one.

```
 axios.get('/getGraph/' + self.teacher)
        then(({
                            data
        }) => {
        self.dataSource.data = []
        data.date.forEach(x => {
            self.dataSource.data.push(x);
        });
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for me. But is this the best answer? What if i select other options has with data in it. It will be okay?